# Solve $x=e^\frac{a}{b+x}$ when $a,b,x>0$

Tags: exponential-function

> If $a,b,x>0$, then solve 
>   $$x=e^\frac{a}{b+x}$$

I just can solve this numerically with given values of $a,b$. Any idea how I can solve this analytically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no closed-form solution in general.  You could write a solution as a formal series in powers of $a$:

$$  
x = 1+\frac{a}{b+1}+{\frac {b-1}{2\, \left( b+1 \right) ^{3}
}}{a}^{2}+{\frac {{b}^{2}-7\,b+4}{6\, \left( b+1 \right) ^{5}}}{a}^{3}
+{\frac {{b}^{3}-25\,{b}^{2}+67\,b-27}{24\, \left( b+1 \right) ^{7}}}{
a}^{4}+{\frac {{b}^{4}-71\,{b}^{3}+531\,{b}^{2}-821\,b+256}{120\,
 \left( b+1 \right) ^{9}}}{a}^{5}+\ldots $$

Comment: How did you find this?

Comment: In Maple:  series(RootOf(x = exp(a/(b+x)), x), a);

Comment: In principle, you can do it with the [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem).

Comment: @RobertIsrael "in principle" XD depends on your sanity level

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to solve analytically such equations. The way to approach such problems is by numerical methods.

$$x=e^{a/(b+x)} \Leftrightarrow x- e^{a/(b+x)} = 0$$

Set a function :

$$f(x) := x- e^{a/(b+x)} $$

And procceed on finding the roots of the equation $f(x) = 0$ using a numerical method, such as for example the *Newton Raphson Method*, since this is a differentiable function.

For *Newton Raphson Method* specifically, you make a sequence, which converges to the solution of your problem, given a starting $x_0$ which can be found by sketching the graph with a computer program.

The sequence :

$$x_{k+1} = x_k - \frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k )}$$

You start with :

$$x_{1} = x_0 - \frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0 )}$$

and then proceed on, until you converge to the root.

You can calculate the *error* of the method with :

$$x_k = x^* + e_k$$
$$\dots$$
$$e_{k+1} \approx \frac{f''(x^*)}{2f'(x^*)}e_{k}^2$$